# I want to call the element that contains "xyz" from vb.net with webbrowser

Tags: vb.net

I have html like this:

```
<input tabindex="0" id="x-widget-2-input" value="xyz" style="width:142px;" class="GP34Q33JX GP34Q33EX" type="text">
```

I want to call the element that contains "xyz" from vb.net with webbrowser, anyone can help?

Comment: Why the `delphi-7` tag?

Comment: What exactly is the meaning of *call the element from vb.net with webbrowser*?